# how to transfer a file from within system partition on android to desktop

Tags: adb, nexus-5, file-system, file-transfer, file-permissions

## background

I'm developing an app that downloads files to the device.. some of these files are acting out and to trouble shoot I want to actually transfer these files to my (mac) desktop and go through them.

So this is what I did:

- i rooted my device
- i know exactly where my file is:

  $adb shell
  $su
  cd /data/user/0/com.app.name.dev/files/34234/
  ls

here i get the file name.. let's say it's called
`file_name.txt`

the problem is when i go to my desktop and do something like

`adb -s $device_id pull /data/user/0/com.app.name.dev/files/34234/file_name.txt`

i get the error message

`remote object '/data/user/0/com.app.name.dev/files/34234/file_name.txt' does not exist`

when i know it does!

- I also tried using `scp` from within the android shell command.. but scp doesn't exist there
- i tried running `adb root` and got

  `adbd cannot run as root in production builds`

any help?

Answer (score -1):

it turns out that i simply should use the `cp` command from within my root android shell.. and copy it to `/mnt/sdcard`.. the rest is obvious after that